# How do you save previous activity data in Kotlin so when you reopen it, the same data is still there?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a quiz app and so far I've made the code for creating a question and answer in one activity which then takes you back to the main activity where a button with the text set to the question is created. I want to have it so that you can click that button and go back into the previous activity where you previously inputted the question and answer specifically for that button and have all of that still there. How exactly would I be able to create something like this? I've only ever seen a Java video for one but never a Kotlin. Here's my code for context:

MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                    Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
        }
    }
}}
```

SecondActivity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener{
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()

            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: If you need to save stuff that survives even when your app is killed and dead or exited, you should use local storage https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#2

Answer (score 0):

you can use onSaveIntanceState method to save current activity data

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putString("activity", "my activity data");
  // etc.
}
```

and for retrieve data when activity resumed you have to use savedInstanceState
in onRestoreInstanceState method or in onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("activity");
}
```