# How do I save inputted edit text when going from Activity A to B and then from A to B again?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a quiz app so that when the user clicks the plus button on the home page it takes them to a page where they input a question and answer and click the check mark and is taken back to the homepage where a new button with the text set to the question is created. I have all of this coded and working except for the part where I can save the previously inputted question/answer activity state if the user wants to edit it with my layout inflator option. However, I have no idea how to have the inputted question and answer saved when starting the intent for the second activity on the homepage. I tried intent flags but they don't work. Whenever I test my application and click edit, it goes to a new second activity and previously inputted text is gone. Can someone please help? Here's my code:

Second Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()
            val answertext = answer.text.toString()
            val sharedPre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit()
            sharedPre.putString("question", questiontext)
            sharedPre.putString("answer", answertext)
            sharedPre.apply()


            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }
    }
```

Main Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent)
                    val loadSharedPre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
                    loadSharedPre.all
                }
                setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                    Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you save previous activity data in Kotlin so when you reopen it, the same data is still there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536400/how-do-you-save-previous-activity-data-in-kotlin-so-when-you-reopen-it-the-same)

Comment: Well no cause thats only specifically for phone orientation change from horizontal to vertical and vice versa.

Comment: both are same. you're distroring first activity. You have to bundle it, pass it to activity 2, and again from activity 2 pass it to activity 1. OR, you can save it in SharedPrefrence.